# Intellij: Is it possible to edit Commit Checks for all projects?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to activate Intellij's commit check "Optimize Imports" for all my projects (all based on different repos). Is that somehow possible?

As a second best: is it possible to set the default for all new projects?

So far, I can only select it manually for every project.
[image: Settings]

Intellij also tells me, that this only affects the current project.
[image: Settings only applied to current project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to activate Intellij's commit check "Optimize Imports"
> for all my projects (all based on different repos). Is that somehow
> possible?

`Optimize Imports` is stored on `workspace.xml` file which stores user-specific settings that by design are not shared. We have a feature request for the possibility to share them. Please vote on the following feature request  [IDEA-259797](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259797) using the thumbs-up button on the right of the issue summary.

> As a second best: is it possible to set the default for all new
> projects?

You can enable the setting at **File | New Projects Setup | Settings for new projects**